# Athena: use only a subset of JSON fields

Tags: json, parquet, amazon-athena

I have a pretty complex nested JSON logs. I'd like to create an Athena external table based on these logs, but only use SOME of the JSON fields in the table.

I have two questions:

1. Do I still have to create a full complex DDL with nested structs even though I don't need most of the fields there?
2. assuming I can do that, and I store the JSON logs in Parquet format in S3 - will Athena scan only those parts/fields of the logs I specify? Or will it do a full scan anyway , for the full price? :-)

a simplified JSON event example:

```
{
  "name": "n1",
  "f1": "v1",
  "group1": {
     "g1F1": "v1",
     "g1F2": "v2",
     "group11": {
         "g11F1": "v1",
         "g11F2": "v2"
     },
     "group12": {
         "g12F1": "v1",
         "g12F2": "v2"
     }
   },
   "group2": {
     "g2F1": "v1",
     "g2F2": "v2",
      ...
   },
   ...
}
```

Lets say I am only interested in the top-level fields "name", "f1" and some nested fields, say "group2"'s fields "g2F1" and "g2F2". 
Could I do something like this:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE mytable (
  name string,
  f1 string,
  group2 struct<g2F1: string, g2F2: string>
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
LOCATION 's3://<mybucket>'
```

?

When I try this approach - the DDL runs with no errors, the table is created, but 'select * from mytable' returns no results ...

Thank you!!

---

Update:

Resolution for Question/Problem 1:
Not sure why, but once I re-uploaded gzipped logs once again into S3 - the table creation and queries started working!

For Question 2 - see Tanveer's answer below.

---

Update 2:

For those who is also considering this option: I got Athena table created with about 6G of zipped data - all is good. However, query execution times are extremely high. A simple query, with a filter on a few fields, takes about 25-30 min.... Considering this is only a POC, using 6G, and I would have a few hundred Ts for real - this option is not feasible for my use case. Granted, I did not use Parquet format - but since I would often need most of the columns, I don't think using Parquet would drastically improve query performance for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answers below.

1. The reason your query is not returning data since Athena does not like line break in the json data. Your table definition is perfect and you don't need to create a table definition on the whole data. Thats the good thing about the schema-on-read. Your whole data should be in same line as below. Then your Athena query will return data. Don't get disheartened. Glue ETL can read json file with line breaks since Glue ETL runs Spark under the hood. So you can convert your json file to parquet using Glue ETL and then create Athena table on top of the parquet data.

   {"name": "n1","f1": "v1","group1": {"g1F1": "v1","g1F2": "v2","group11": {"g11F1": "v1","g11F2": "v2"},"group12": {"g12F1": "v1","g12F2": "v2"}},"group2": {"g2F1": "v1","g2F2": "v2"}}
2. Once you convert the data into parquet, you will be charged only for the column you use in the query, not for the whole table as explained [here](https://aws.amazon.com/athena/pricing/).

Comment: Thank you, Tanveer, for a quick answer!! Sorry if I was not clear - my logs do have one event (full nested JSON) per line - so it is not an issue with multi-line JSON. You did get me thinking along those lines though... so I chopped off most of the parts of the log, left just 3 top-level fields, and only one nested group - and on the simplified log structure the table/query did work!! So, now the question is - what could be wrong in the body of my JSON events that make Athena fail to read the data... I guess I'll start added sub-elements one by one to try to isolate the issue. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks Marina. Can you please share the logfile with 2 o 3 full events with all the levels. You can replace the actual valuea with some dummy values. I would like to see the full structure. Lets see if I can help.

Comment: Thank you for your help, Tanveer! Well, I don't exactly know what happened.... but once I re-uploaded the full logs into S3 (gzipped) - I was able to create the same table over all data with no issues.... I will update my question. I do wonder - is there any way to inspect internal logs with potential errors when Athena reads data in? Not the query info CloudWatch logs - but the actual Athena logs ? Thanks!!

Comment: Hi Marina, I don't think we can access Athena logs. Currently we can only see Cloudwatch/CloudTrail logs